# Why is get-task-allow not showing in my Entitlements.plist file?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

So I am trying to set up my first ios app for add hoc distribution and I get the dreaded "Invalid Profile: developer build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to true." error.

So I fumble around the internet trying to figure it out before I ask for help and come up with changing my "Entitlements.plist" file and change get-task-allow to true. Well ... when I go to xcode4 and look at my "Entitlements.plist" file, its not there. 
[image]

I try to add it and this shows up.
[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Can Be Debugged** key is a user-friendly representation of `get-task-allow`.

Comment: Where can 'Can Be Debugged' be found?

Comment: Look at the screenshot in the original post, Ben -- that's where it is.