# App targeting OS 5.1 does not install on iOS 6

Tags: ios6, installation

My app was compiled for iOS 5.1 and later. I could install it on iPad 1 using testflight. However, the app fails to install on iPad 3 with iOS 6. Both devices are in the provisioning profile.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Here are my build settings:

Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS6.0)

iOS Deployment Target: iOS 5.1

Valid Architecture: armv7 armv7s

Comment: Have you checked get-task-allow (Can Be Debugged) per this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745794/why-is-get-task-allow-not-showing-in-my-entitlements-plist-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's the provisioning profile. There were several profiles on my machine and I selected the wrong one when creating the IPA file.